# How to convert all urls of my Project in lowercase in angular js application?

Tags: url-routing, lowercase

Is there any solution to implement a single method or setting one Place and can apply it to all Urls of my project? Like `Web.config` or `App.config` Setting or in single JS file?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:- Solution For MVC Application**
one solution i have found for my Question Is That 
set this 
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "VSMDiamonds.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```